# Estimation of average treatment effect based on nearest neighbor matching

Tags: r, k-nearest-neighbour, matching, treatment-effect

I would like to use R to duplicate the treatment effect estimation method used in Stata.  Specifically, [this is the Stata method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEqwQ0FI2Vg) I would like to duplicate.

I have tried the package `MatchIt` and `Zelig` in R, but the result was quite different from the result I had in Stata.

```
m.out1 = matchit(treatment ~ high_peak + hour, method="nearest", data=regres_LNG)
z.out1 = zelig(IPPLNG.gen ~ high_peak + hour,
               data=match.data(m.out1,"control"), model="ls")
x.out1 = setx(z.out1, data=match.data(m.out1, "treat", cond=TRUE))


s.out1 = sim(z.out1, x=x.out1)
summary(s.out1)

z.out2  = zelig(IPPLNG.gen~hour+high_peak,
                data=match.data(m.out1,"treat"), model="ls")
x.out2  = setx(z.out2, data=match.data(m.out1,"control"), cond=TRUE)
s.out2  = sim(z.out2, x=x.out2)
ate.all = c(s.out1$sim.out[[1]][1][[1]][[1]], -s.out2$sim.out[[1]][1][[1]][[1]])
```

(Also, I learned this method in [the pdf](https://imai.fas.harvard.edu/research/files/matchit.pdf))

Besides, I tried the linear regression model including treatment as a independent variable, but the coefficient and p-value was still different.

```
m.data   = match.data(m.out1)
lm_treat = lm(IPPLNG.gen~事件+hour+high_peak, data=m.data)
summary(lm_treat)
```

Hence, I would like to know how to duplicate the treatment effect estimation within nearest neighborhood matching in Stata to R and the difference between these two methods.

Comment: One immediate thing is that `matchit()` uses the logit function, i.e., `distance = "logit"` by default for the distance metric. Specify `distance = "mahalanobis"` to match what they use in the youtube video.

Comment: I just specified `distance="mahalanobis"`. But the result was still different.  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Despite good documentation for `teffects nnmatch` and the R package `Matching`, the answers are slightly different, but I'm not exactly sure why. However, here is how you can get close to a similar answer in R:

```
d <- haven::read_dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/cattaneo2.dta")
library(Matching)
m.out <- with(d, Match(Y = bweight, 
                       Tr = mbsmoke, 
                       X = data.frame(fage, mage, mmarried, prenatal1),
                       Z = data.frame(fage, mage),
                       estimand = "ATE",
                       BiasAdjust = TRUE,
                       exact = c(fage = FALSE, mage = FALSE, 
                                 mmarried = TRUE, prenatal1 = TRUE)))
summary(m.out)
```

The `MatchIt` package cannot do this kind of analysis. The philosophy behind it is different from that underlying `teffects nnmatch`. The `Matching` package comes quite close in that it has many of the same options as `teffects nnmatch` and was built on a similar philosophy (and even uses fairly similar syntax elements). Using this code, I get an ATE of -250.18 (27.807), whereas `teffects nnmatch` in the video gave an ATE of -244.32 (27.269), which lead to the same substantive conclusion.

Comment: I have tried it. I think it's the most similar method in R. Thank you